# How to load JS in a dynamically loaded content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best approach to apply JS to the dynamically loaded content. Let say I have this:

form.html (to load dynamically)

main.html with a button, when clicked DIV shown and form.html dynamically loaded.

In my main.html I have JS that suppose to find form tag (from a dynamically loaded form) and process it further (I use jQuery). I could have included that JS in form.html and then it works, but what I want to do is to have my JS in main.html and yet be able to manipulate dynamically loaded content with it. Can that be achieved? Thanks.

EDITED:

form.html

```
<form id="f"><input name="i"/></form>
```

main.html

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#b').on('click', function() {
    $('#div').load('form.hmtl');

    //Again, I know that I can pass JS code into load() call. I want to be able
    //to avoid that.
  });

  var $form = $('#f');

  $form.mask() //it's a jquery plugin that blocks mouse clicks on a specific element

  //note that form is not yet loaded. I know that I can pack the code above into a
  //function and pass it with .on('click', function(){}) call. The question is:
  //is it possible to avoid that.
});
</script>
<button id="b">Load Form</button>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with event delegation. Say the following `input` is loaded in dynamically:

```
<input type="button" value="click me" id="btnTest" />
```

To capture this elements click event, we'll bind the event to the container of the element (in this example `document`) and listen for a click on that element:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnTest', function() {
    console.log("You clicked dynamic content!");
});
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: well that's true, I can use .on() for events. BUT, how then i attach event on load. I want to mask form, load more JSON data, and then unmask form after JSON data is ready (and all this on load of the dynamic content)... Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your AJAX calls, you can bind the handlers at load time as well.

Comment: I think `on` is going to be the easiest route.

Answer (score 0):

Either you process it after changing the DOM as tymeJV suggested or you add a ready-event to the newly added content and invoke the desired code from the ready event. I would prefer first and second only if you do not have direct control about the dom change.